# Highcharts: Custom area outline for line joining each marker

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to get a gradient color applied onto outline of an area series and the color depends on colors of both markers at the two ends, which'll be different for each line.
Used, highcharts multicolor_series module, for some reason it only draws and colors outline for 2 lines and doesn't draw/completes the last one. Here's my JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkk/s29d51zt/872/
Can you please help me solve this, where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
"credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "chart": {
    // backgroundColor: '#F5F7F7',
    "polar": true,
    "height": 190,
    "width": 290,
    "minWidth": 250,
    "marginBottom": -25,
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": [
        "WhitneyNarrBook",
        "Roboto",
        "Arial",
        "sans-serif"
      ],
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": 11,
      "letterSpacing": "-0.06px",
      "lineHeight": "16px"
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "gridZIndex": 4,
    "gridLineColor": "#dce1e6",
    "lineColor": "#dce1e6",
    "categories": [
      "Cat1",
      "Cat2",
      "Cat3"
    ],
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on",
    "lineWidth": 0,
    "labels": {
      "useHTML": true,
      "align": "center",
      "style": {
        "whiteSpace": "nowrap",
        "color": "#26415e",
        "fontSize": "12px"
      }
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "gridLineInterpolation": "polygon",
    "gridZIndex": 4,
    "gridLineColor": "#dce1e6",
    "lineColor": "#dce1e6",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
    "showFirstLabel": false,
    "showLastLabel": true,
    "tickInterval": 25,
    "labels": {
      "align": "center",
      "y": 5,
      "x": 0,
      "style": {
        "color": "#333333",
        "fontSize": "10px"
      }
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "marker": {
        "radius": 2.5
      },
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "inactive": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    },
    "area": {
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  },
  "series": [{
      "showInLegend": false,
      "data": [
        100,
        100,
        100
      ],
      "color": {
        "radialGradient": {
          "cx": 0.5,
          "cy": 0.7,
          "r": 0.5
        },
        "stops": [
          [
            0,
            "#DFA124"
          ],
          [
            0.55,
            "#AF9D3F"
          ],
          [
            0.75,
            "#5A9772"
          ],
          [
            1,
            "#229595"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle"
      },
      "fillOpacity": 0.5,
      "type": "area",
      "lineColor": "transparent"
    },
    {
      "showInLegend": false,
      "data": [{
          "y": 33,
          "color": "#AF9D3F"
        },
        {
          "y": 65,
          "color": "#229595"
        },
        {
          "y": 28,
          "color": "#DFA124"
        }
      ],
      zIndex: 5,
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      "type": "area",
      //lineWidth: 5,
      //lineColor: 'gray',
      "color": "transparent",
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle"
      }
    },
    {
      "showInLegend": false,
      "data": [
        [
          33,
          100
        ],
        [
          65,
          100
        ],
        [
          28,
          100
        ]
      ],
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      "type": "arearange",
      "fillColor": "white",
      "opacity": 1,
      "lineColor": "transparent",
      "marker": {
        "fillColor": "#dce1e6",
        "lineColor": "#dce1e6"
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'coloredline',
      showInLegend: false,
      pointPlacement: "on",
      data: [{
        y: 33,
        segmentColor: {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y1: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            //[0, '#AF9D3F'], // start
            [0.5, '#AF9D3F'], // middle
            [1, '#229595'] // end
          ]
        }
      }, {
        y: 65,
        segmentColor: {
        linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y1: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            //[0, '#AF9D3F'], // start
            [0.25, '#DFA124'],
            [1, '#229595'] // middle
          ]
        }
      }, {
        y: 28,
        "segmentColor": {
          "linearGradient": {
            "x1": 0,
            "x2": 0,
            "y1": 0,
            "y2": 1
          },
          "stops": [
            [
              0.5,
              "#229595"
            ],
            [
              1,
              "#DFA124"
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      ]
    }
  ]
```

[image: Missing outline on left side of colored chart]

Comment: Its not playing with the x1 and x2 of linearGradient property and stop colors? I mean, outline is suppose to be there but it has sane color as area so its difficult to recognize

Comment: I doubt that, here's fiddle link with just outline colors, and I don't see the third outline on the graph: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkk/s29d51zt/881/

Comment: Hi @PGKK, You can add another point to close the line. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1rx0g82z/

Comment: Thank you , yes adding another point does close the line. I couldn't find any support on smoothing out lines between two points, like spline. I also noticed, that if "type: spline", is provided with 2 data points it results into a straight line. Can you please help me find a solution to add curved borders on my graph, (for now it only draws straight lines) (There's a different color on each border/outline which depends on marker colors at the ends) - https://jsfiddle.net/pgkk/s29d51zt/1055/

Comment: Why would you like to add a spline only with two points? It is enough to add one spline series with 3 points. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9o80vsj4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each outline you can add separate line series and with corresponding gradient and disabled marker.
Try fiddle link

```
    {
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      "showInLegend": false,
      data: [
        [33],
        [65],
        [null]
      ],

      type: 'line',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      color: {
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y1: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, '#AF9D3F'],
          [1, '#229595']
        ]
      }

    }, {
      "showInLegend": false,
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      data: [
        [null],
        [65],
        [28],
      ],

      type: 'line',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      color: {
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y1: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, '#AF9D3F'],
          [1, '#229595']
        ]
      }


    }, {
      "showInLegend": false,
      "pointPlacement": "on",
      data: [
        [33],
        [null],
        [28],
      ],
      type: 'line',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      color: {
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y1: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, '#AF9D3F'],
          [1, '#AF9D3F']
        ]
      }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koushlendra/o5dujm0z/719/

Comment: Thanks Koushlendra! This does solve my problem of applying different colors on my chart border. I'm also trying to add spline and make the graph smoother, but since there are just 2 data points used for coloring outline it results into a straight line. Could you please help me with smoothing out the outline of graph. Thanks in advance! Here's my fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkk/s29d51zt/1055/